# awk: replacing "c" in Fortran codes with "!"

Tags: string, replace, awk, gfortran

I am trying to adapt the [CAMx](http://www.camx.com/) software for the GNU/gfortran compiler (this open source is supported by commercial compilers only).

After extending the Makefile I found that I have to replace all "c" and "C" characters in the first column with the "!" character in many *.inc and *.f free-format Fortran files.

Could you please advice me some awk script which would process all source files (listed out through ls */*.F,ls */*.inc) and made the wanted "C/c"->"!" first column replacement inside them ?

Yours, Miro

Comment: post some sample input and expected output but this is generally not possible without writing an interpreter for the language in question.

Comment: @EdMorton This appears to be about fixed-format FORTRAN. A `c` in the first column marks the line as a comment, and I think OP has a FORTRAN implementation where comments are marked with `!` instead.

Comment: @Wintermute and you can't have a string or something extending across lines so the string could have a `c` inside it that just happens to be at the start of a line?

Comment: @EdMorton I don't think so, no. (Although I do have to disclaim that my experience with FORTRAN is very, very limited, so it is possible that someone who knows more than I comes along shortly and shows me up)

Comment: last time I programmed in Fortran was 35 years ago. I wrote the code in a grid on sheets of paper, one character per cell, and it was sent by paper mail to the secretary at the local college who typed it onto punchcards which were then handed to the technician to run through the mainframe and later they collect the results to give to the secretary who then paper mailed it back to me so 1 week after writing it I got the results back and typically found I had forgot a semi-colon. So, I don't remember much about the language but I'm hoping the development process has improved since then :-).

Answer (score 2):

It's easier with sed:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/^[Cc]/!/' filename
```

Then for all `.f` and `.inl` files in a directory:

```
 find directory -type f \( -name \*.f -or -name \*.inl \) -exec sed -i.bak 's/^[Cc]/!/' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}.bak' \;
```

Where `directory` has to be replaced with the directory in which the source code lies. This will also handle subdirectories; if that isn't wanted, pass `-maxdepth 1` as well or use

```
for file in *.f *.inl; do
  sed -i.bak 's/^[Cc]/!/' "$file" && rm "$file".bak
done
```

instead.

Comment: Why do you use `-i.bak` but then immediately delete the .bak file? `-exec ... \+` would reduce the number of calls to sed/rm

Comment: @glennjackman The second `-exec` will only be run if `sed` succeeded. In case of an error, you'll still have the backup. Also, this way BSD sed will not complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose `sed`.

```
sed -i 's/^[cC]/!/' *.f *.inc
```

If you want to descend into subdirectories, you can do this with bash:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
sed -i 's/^[cC]/!/' **/*.{f,inc}
```